Fastest way to find SQL intersection between 2 subsections of a huge dataset?
I have a gigantic indexed (104 million row) table of docs, pages and words:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    doc_id integer,
    page_id integer,
    word_id integer
);

CREATE INDEX my_table_word ON my_table (word_id);
CREATE INDEX my_table_doc ON my_table (doc_id);
CREATE INDEX my_table_page my_table (page_id);

I want to find pages within the same documents that have both word A and word B. My current attempts are as follows:
Attempt 1 - aggregate things:
SELECT doc_id, page_id
FROM my_table
WHERE word_id in (123, 456)
group by 1,2 
having count(distinct word_id) = 2

-- ~39k row result, took 20 seconds

Attempt 2) with CTEs, marginally faster
with foo as (
    select doc_id, page_id
    from my_table
    where word_id = 123 -- foo -- 44k rows
),

bar as (
    select doc_id, page_id
    from my_table
    where word_id = 456 -- bar -- 439k rows
)

select f.doc_id, f.page_id
from foo f
inner join bar b on f.doc_id = b.doc_id and f.page_id = b.page_id

-- same results, takes 15 seconds

Attempt 3) - doing an INTERSECT between the two CTEs is exactly the same 15 seconds, probably same query plan.
Is there a faster way to do this? I'm hoping to get this down to < 1 second for a web app with somewhat impatient users.


Your title is misleading, you are only dealing with one dataset. -


OK, 2 sub-datasets within 1 dataset, have updated the title if that matters so much

I think my question is pretty clear no? How to find the intersection between those two words? Seems nitpicky to be discussing the title unless it is very unclear.

@LittleBobbyTables 1) You said you need to "find documents that have both word A and word B" but your queries look for only those docs with at least one page with both of them on that same one page. If you're looking for entire documents that mention both words anywhere in them (e.g. word A on page 1, word B on page 2), these queries don't look right. 2) If these queries yield the same results in your test, be warned that it might be an accident: in this test, one finds 18, the other 20 (the 2nd one returns duplicates).

@Zegarek Yes I'm trying to find pages with the same word in them. Have updated the description.

@LittleBobbyTables is page_id actually a page identifier? Or can different pages share the same page_id (but have different doc_id)?

Try a self join:
SELECT DISTINCT doc_id, page_id
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b ON b.page_id = a.page_id
  AND b.word_id = 456
WHERE a.word_id = 123

With an index
CREATE INDEX ON my_table (word_id, page_id, doc_id);

which is a covering index, allowing an index-only query.

I think this index is the magic OP is looking for

@Zegarek I didn't realise word_id was not unique per page_id. Fixed now? BTW your demo query that produces 71 is incorrect; it only find pages that have only words 123 and 456, not pages that contain at least 123 and 456 - ie pages that contain other words too.

@Bohemian Thanks for taking a look. I added an edit here: distinct you had already added was part of the problem, joining on only page_id was another - that's what made it count matches on the same page but in different documents, which is why it was that far off. I'm not sure which of my queries you're saying was wrong. The demos I always add have a seed saved so you can inspect the results and see they're all correct: here's the setup that produced 71, with all other words shown - you can see the docs and pages found all contain more than 123 and 456.

@Zegarek this is the query that's incorrect SELECT distinct doc_id, page_id FROM my_table WHERE word_id in (123, 456) group by 1,2  having count(distinct word_id) = 2

@Bohemian That's the OP's query. Mine are lower down the page. Also, that one works fine because it's first grabbing doc and page based on either of the two words, then leaving only those that have exactly 2 different words - it does not filter out those that have other words because in that context only the 2 are considered. Here it's shown with the first 5 docs&pages it found - it's all fine.

This is great and really fast thanks very much. Query now runs in under 1 second!

@LittleBobbyTables You might want to try the exists example - it upgrades the merge join this does to a merge semi-join. 1.2ms down to 0.8ms here

@LittleBobbyTables I made a small error in the index definition (doc and page in wrong order). Try dropping and recreating using CREATE INDEX ON my_table (word_id, page_id, doc_id). You'll probably find it's even faster.

@Bohemian Why would that change anything?

@Zegarek it should be faster because there are less pages than docs that match, so fewer index pages will be accessed. Also, I just noticed you edited my query to also join on doc, which is a mistake since if it matches on page it must match on doc (there are many pages per doc, but exactly 1 doc per page), making the test for doc redundant. Your edit, which has now been undone, fundamentally changed the query. Please do not edit other people's code, unless fixing an obvious syntax error or to fix formatting where the formatting is absent or very poor.

@LittleBobbyTables I have restored my original query. Let me know if it's faster.

@Bohemian But page 1 in doc X isn't the same page as page 1*in doc Y and OP said they're after "pages within the same documents that have both word A and word B". If you only join on page_id, you're assuming the two words also coincide if they are on the same page of two different documents. You could interpret it as the same page, but not the same page within the same document, which seems to be the goal. Each time I'm adding a link to a demo showing what I mean, and I already showed joining on only page_id is both slower and incorrect, both due to the flood of false positives

A basic intersect seems to perform fine:
demo at db<>fiddle
select doc_id, page_id
from my_table
where word_id = 456
INTERSECT
select doc_id, page_id
from my_table
where word_id = 123;

In my test on 800k docs, 100 pages each, using 1k words, it runs about as fast as your second example, while being simpler and duplicate-free because it defaults to INTERSECT DISTINCT.
You can also use an exists:
select distinct doc_id, page_id
from my_table as a
where word_id = 456
  and exists(select from my_table as b 
             where a.doc_id=b.doc_id
               and a.page_id=b.page_id
               and word_id = 123);

And that runs about just as fast.
Still, you were right to try and find everything you needed in a single pass, a single query, using aggregation and having:
select doc_id, page_id
from my_table
where word_id in(456,123)
group by doc_id, page_id
having bool_or(word_id=456) 
   and bool_or(word_id=123);

The two bool_or()'s check if any of the words on the page is your first word, and the same for the other one.
As suggested by @Bohemian, a fully covering index can speed things up significantly:
CREATE INDEX my_table_word_page_doc ON my_table (word_id,doc_id,page_id);

SELECT DISTINCT doc_id, page_id
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b using (doc_id,page_id)
WHERE b.word_id = 456
  AND a.word_id = 123


Besides the answers about how to write the SQL, you may be able to get a speedup by turning your indexes into covering indexes.
CREATE INDEX my_table_word ON my_table (word_id, page_id, doc_id);

For example, with this simple query:
SELECT doc_id, page_id
FROM my_table
WHERE word_id in (123, 456)
group by 1,2 

Since all the values involved are in the index, the DB should not have to go read the rows from the table to get the values of doc_id and page_id because they are in the index.
How well this works undoubtedly differs from RDBMS to RDBMS.

Wow that is super fast! Query now runs in under 1 second. Wild! I need to study more about how this 3-col covering index is better than individual indices. Thank you.

The short version is that an index lets the DB tell which row it needs to get from the table. Typically if you're doing SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = :userid you're wanting all the cols. In your case, all the data values are in the index, and the DB never needs to read rows from the table.
